# ActiveDirectory Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to authenticate Intranet users using `ActiveDirectory`. The system should not ask for any user name or password. If the Logged In user is in the AD then the system should automatically validate and redirect to a specific page.

I have tried lots of code from net but all the Examples are using Password at least once...

Comment: What form of `ASP.NET` are you using? MVC? Did you take a look at the AD sample code generated by the MVC template?

Comment: No I am using ASP.NET 2.0 @ChrFin

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? Do you see Authentication link on right side when you click your website in IIS?  Once you double click authentication, what modes of authentication are enabled?

Also, are your users going to use any browser or just Internet Explorer?

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 with Windows Authentication Enabled. The process should cross browser supported. @greatbear302

Answer (score 0):

You can configure windows integrated authentication by setting up your config and IIS server, for full details have a read of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817643(pandp.10).aspx)

Comment: Link-only answers are not good, because they can get useless if the link "goes away". Can you please outline at least the basic steps described in the link?

Comment: I have tried the link but it's asking for password for the first time.. @Dan Hedges

Comment: @ChrFin While Link-only answers aren't great, I've found lately that they tend to go along with questions that lack code, or are otherwise incomplete. Without more concrete context for examples, often simply pointing someone to the correct documentation is the best course. That said, I would have hoped to see a more specific guide targeted at integrated auth, rather than authentication in general.